# JavaFX Button's disableProperty bind to multiple BooleanBindings

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I have several TextFields and a submit button. I want my button to be disabled unless all the textfields have been validated. Below is my code for the BooleanBindings:

```
        BooleanBinding firstNameValidation, middleNameValidation, lastNameValidation, 
        usernameValidation, passwordValidation, retypePasswordValidation, emailValidation, phoneNumberValidation;

        firstNameValidation = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(()->{
            if(employee.setFirstName(txtFirstName.getText()) == 0){
                piFirstName.setProgress(100);
                return true;
            } else {
                piFirstName.setProgress(0);
                return false;
            }
        }, txtFirstName.textProperty());

        middleNameValidation = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(()->{
            if(employee.setMiddleName(txtMiddleName.getText()) == 0){
                piMiddleName.setProgress(100);
                return true;
            } else {
                piMiddleName.setProgress(0);
                return false;
            }
        }, txtMiddleName.textProperty());
```

..and so on.

This is how I try to bind the disableProperty of the submit button to the BooleanBindings:

```
btnSetPermissions.disableProperty().bind(firstNameValidation.not().or(middleNameValidation.not()).or(lastNameValidation.not())
                .or(usernameValidation.not()).or(passwordValidation.not()).or(retypePasswordValidation.not())
                .or(emailValidation.not()).or(phoneNumberValidation.not()));
```

It works, but if the first condition returns false, it doesn't check the rest of the conditions because of the OR-operation.

I can't seem to find a solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the first condition returns false, why should it check the other conditions?

Comment: Meaning, if the first condition is false the buttons should be disabled right?

Comment: Because of the ProgressIndicator in the IF-statements. I want them to indicate dynamically when the input is correct even if the textfield hasn't lost focus. Maybe I schould use a ChangeListener instead..

Comment: It's pretty unusual (and nonstandard) for a `set` method to return a value. Can you explain what `employee.setFirstName()` does? It looks like you are trying to do too much work in the bindings, and should separate these out into different pieces of functionality.

Comment: The set method validates the input and if it is correct returns 0, else returns error code. I will try to separate the validation from the set method. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing your functionality too much. Separate it out into constituent components:

```
firstNameValidation = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
    String firstName = txtFirstName.getText();
    if (/* firstName is valid */) {
        return true ;
    } else {
        return false ;
    }
}, txtFirstName.textProperty());

employee.firstNameProperty().bind(txtFirstName.textProperty());
// if you want employee.firstName to change only if the name is valid,
// use a listener here instead of the binding above:
txtFirstName.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
    if (firstNameValidation.get()) {
        employee.setFirstName(newText);
    }
});

piFirstName.bind(Bindings.when(firstNameValidation).then(100).otherwise(0));

// similarly for other properties...

// then (this logic is equivalent to yours, but easier to read imho)

btnSetPermissions.disableProperty().bind(
    (firstNameValidation.and(middleNameValidation)
     .and(userNameValidation).and(passwordValidation)
     .and(retypePasswordValidation).and(emailValidation)
     .and(phoneNumberValidation)
    ).not());
```

Note you can, of course, reduce the code by moving anything repetitive to a method in the usual way:

```
private BooleanBinding createValidationBinding(
        TextField field, Predicate<String> validationRule, 
        StringProperty boundValue, ProgressIndicator indicator) {

    BooleanBinding validation = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
        String value = field.getText();
        return validationRule.test(value);
    }, field.textProperty());

    field.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> {
        if (binding.get()) {
            boundValue.set(newText);
        }
    });

    indicator.progressProperty().bind(Bindings.when(validation).then(100).otherwise(0));

    return validation ;
}
```

Then you can do

```
firstNameValidation = createValidationBinding(txtFirstName, 
    name -> /* boolean indicating if name is valid */,
    employee.firstNameProperty(), piFirstName);
```

and similarly for the other fields.

Comment: Thank you. I will separate out the validation from the set methods and use your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, this is what I do:

```
btnSetPermissions.disableProperty.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
    if (!validateFirstName() ||
        !validateMiddleName() /* and so on */)
        return true;
    else return false;
}, firstNameProperty(), middleNameProperty() /* and other properties*/ ));

public boolean validateFirstName() {
    // Your validation logic
}

public boolean validateMiddleName() {
    // Your validation logic
}

/* Other validation methods */
```

There is no need to create so many objects (those `BindingExpression` objects), and you can easily use conditional operators like `||` and `&&` which will guarantee skipping of non-essential checks whenever possible.

Comment: In this case, though, the OP has several other values bound to the individual validation bindings...

Comment: @James_D Oh, I missed the part regarding `ProgressIndicator`.